# Replacement iMac G3 Chasis?

Tags: imac

Just purchased an old used iMac G3 but unfortunately the plastic subframe is pretty brittle. I doubt it's something that I could gorilla-glue back together. Does anybody know where I could buy a new subframe or a new chassis altogether?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Question is: does it boot?

Comment: Ebay doesn't work?  https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=imac+g3&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR1.TRC0.A0.H0.Ximac+g3+parts.TRS0&_nkw=imac+g3+parts&_sacat=0

Comment: @icondeamon It will after I reload Mac OS.

Comment: @allan I thought about it but was wondering if anyone just flat out sold parts.  I'll probably end up going the ebay route.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no vendor that sells the slot loading inner bezel for your imac whether it’s OEM or aftermarket.

You could purchase a machine from ebay (or similar) and hope they pack it properly so as not to destroy the inner bezel in shipping, or you can try and gorrilla glue the original bezel together so you can scan and 3-d print a new one or hire someone to fabricate a replacement.